# Add "rename" to windows save duplicate dialog?

Tags: windows, rename, duplicate

### Error message

**Copy File**

There is already a file with the same name in this location.  Click the file you want to keep.

*Copy and replace.*

*Don't copy.*

### Actual behavior

When I download a file of the same name to my downloads directory, I get a dialog that essentially says `replace` or `do not save`.  I need to rename an existing file.  It's very time consuming for repetitive tasks.

### Desired behavior

A `rename` option is added to this dialog.  I can rename `by default`, so that I do not need to click this option every time.

Comment: And what browser might that be?

Comment: Using Chrome.  Windows Explorer is where I get the dialog, though.